# Check if list of lists of lists contains a specific list

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains other lists with coordinates for multiple tile positions and I need to check if that list contains another list of coordinates, like in this example:

```
totalList = [ [[0,1], [2,7], [6,3]], [[2,3], [6,1], [4,1]] ]

redList = [ [0,1], [2,7], [6,3] ]

if totalList contains redList:
   #do stuff
```

Can you please help me find out how to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use a containment test:

```
if redList in totalList:
```

This returns `True` for your sample data:

```
>>> totalList = [ [[0,1], [2,7], [6,3]], [[2,3], [6,1], [4,1]] ]
>>> redList = [ [0,1], [2,7], [6,3] ]
>>> redList in totalList
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `in` keyword to determine if a `list` (or any other Python container) contains an element:

```
totalList = [ [[0,1], [2,7], [6,3]], [[2,3], [6,1], [4,1]] ]
redList = [ [0,1], [2,7], [6,3] ]
redList in totalList
```

returns

```
True
```

---

So if you do:

```
if redList in totalList:
    #do stuff
```

Your code will then `do stuff`.

---

> I need to know if totalList contains a list that has exactly the same elements as redList.

We see that list implements `__contains__`

```
>>> help(list.__contains__)
Help on wrapper_descriptor:

__contains__(...)
    x.__contains__(y) <==> y in x
```

and from the docs:

> `__contains__`
>   [Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if item is in self, false otherwise.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details)

And:

> [The operators in and not in test for collection membership.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) x in s evaluates to true if x is a member of the collection s, and false otherwise. x not in s returns the negation of x in s. The collection membership test has traditionally been bound to sequences; an object is a member of a collection if the collection is a sequence and contains an element equal to that object. However, it make sense for many other object types to support membership tests without being a sequence. In particular, dictionaries (for keys) and sets support membership testing.
>
> For the list and tuple types, x in y is true if and only if there
>   exists an index i such that x == y[i] is true.

So we know that one of the elements must be equal to that of redList.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `in` operator:

```
>>> totalList = [ [[0,1], [2,7], [6,3]], [[2,3], [6,1], [4,1]] ]
>>> redList = [ [0,1], [2,7], [6,3] ]
>>> redList in totalList
True
>>> if redList in totalList:
...     print('list found')
...
list found
>>>
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in):

> The operators `in` and `not in` test for membership. `x in s` evaluates to
>   true if `x` is a member of `s`, and false otherwise. `x not in s` returns
>   the negation of `x in s`.