# How to check if a list partially matches one of the lists in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I would like to check if a list is a sublist if a bigger list of lists. It would be easy to check if it is just in the list of lists but a partial match is also acceptable.

In this example it should return `True`:

```
list = [1,4,9]
listoflists = [[1,2,3], [1,3,4,7,9], [6,8]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Check if list of lists of lists contains a specific list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483730/python-check-if-list-of-lists-of-lists-contains-a-specific-list)

Comment: No. That question doesn't deal with partial matches.

Comment: Gotcha, you should make that part of your question title then, since otherwise this looks like a duplicate.

Comment: What do you want to happen with duplicate elements? For example if list=[1,4,4,9] but listoflists has only one 4 do you want it True or False?

Comment: `s = set(lst); any(s.issubset(set(l)) for l in listoflists)`

Comment: alani what about list [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,9] in the following example? Your code would return true which is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example works by:

- Iterating over each sublist within `lol`
- Generating a list representing the intersection of the current sublist and `lol` (stored each iteration as `temp`)
- Comparing `sorted()` versions of `temp` and `l`, returning `True` if a match is found.
- Returning `False` if all sublists are checked with no match found

The function will return `True` if either a full match is found between elements of `l` and any sublist of `lol`, or in "partial match" cases in which all elements of `l` are present within any sublist of `lol`.

```py
def compare_sublists(l, lol):
    for sublist in lol:
        temp = [i for i in sublist if i in l]
        if sorted(temp) == sorted(l):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Updated thanks to feedback from @JasonYang. Included sorting of lists before comparison and fixed initial erroneous list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
any([all([list.count(i)<=x.count(i) for i in list]) for x in listoflists])
```

Comment: Answer for list = [1, 4, 8] should be False, not True ?

Answer (score -1):

```py
from itertools import repeat

def is_sub_list(a, b):
    if [] in (a, b):
        return False
    c = set(a)
    d = map(set, b)
    return True if any(map(set.issubset, repeat(c), d)) else False

lst1 = [1, 3, 9]
lst2 = [1, 3, 8]
lst_of_lst = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 7, 9], [6, 8]]

print(is_sub_list(lst1, lst_of_lst))  # True
print(is_sub_list(lst2, lst_of_lst))  # False
```

Comment: I considered a solution similar to yours at first - i.e converting `list` to a set and using `list.issubset` for each sublist. 


However this is inaccurate when seeking to ascertain whether a `list` is a subset of any nested `list` instances since a `set` will not store duplicate values and a `list` will. 


Using your function and `lst_of_lst` from the example given in your answer. `is_sub_list([1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3], lst_of_lst)` will return `True` when `[1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]` is not a sublist contained within `lst_of_lst`.

Comment: @JPI93 The same result for your solution; >>> compare_sublists([1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3], listoflists)
True; duplicate values is not considered, otherwise it will become more complex to find the answer.

Comment: Fixed this issue in my code now - thanks for pointing it out - had messed up writing out my list comprehension and didn't think to sort lists before comparison, should function fine as a solution now. Duplicate values probably should be considered, otherwise this question would be concerned with sets and not lists (as specified by OP).