# Django - Unique Collection of Foreign Keys Constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models like so:

```py
class Group(...):
    pass

class Identifier(...):
    value = models.CharField(...)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', ..., related_named = 'identifiers')
```

How can I:

1. restrict a `Group` to only have at most 4 `Identifiers`?
2. Ensure that any combination of up to 4 `Identifiers` (the value of the identifier) is unique across all `Groups`?

For part 2, here is an example of the flattened `Groups` table:

```
row | id__0__val | id__1__val | id__2__val | id__3__val 
--- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------
  0 |       abc  |        123 |        xyz |        456
  1 |       abc  |        123 |        xyz |          -   <-- valid (nulls are okay)
  2 |       123  |        abc |        xyz |        456   <-- invalid (same combo as row 0)
```

Previously I have tried (something like) this, but it seems messy, has limited functionality, and I'm not sure it will even work:

```py
class Group(...):
    id__0 = models.OneToOneField('Identifier', blank = True, null = True, ...)
    id__1 = models.OneToOneField('Identifier', blank = True, null = True, ...)
    id__2 = models.OneToOneField('Identifier', blank = True, null = True, ...)
    id__3 = models.OneToOneField('Identifier', blank = True, null = True, ...)

    class Meta: 
        unique_together = ('id__0__value', 'id__1__value', 'id__2__value', 'id__3__value')
```

What is a better way to handle this constraint?

Comment: I'm not sure it would work for reverse relations (or aggregations like `count`), but did you try using a Check constraint (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint)? Also you didn't specify it, but if you're using Postgres, you could maybe get away with and ArrayField instead of enumerate relations in an hard coded way, even though it wouldn't be very clean either? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)

Comment: No I have not seen Check constraints before and yes I am using Postgres - how would an ArrayField solve some of these problems?

Comment: You can restrict the size of an ArrayField (ie. to 4 items) and you could probably perform checks on it. Downside though: it cannot really hold related fields references and would end up in weak matching. In the end I think this downside is quite heavy. Sadly though, Django does not seem to allow handling uniqueness on a list of relations. BTW. I think you second solution would work as well, as Postgres consider NULLs as distinct values (not blanks though, so `blank=False` should be better IMO)

Comment: Do you need the database to enforce this constraint? Or would it be sufficient to handle the validation in Python only?

Answer (score 1):

My take on this, but doing it through a `clean` method:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    MAX_IDENTIFIERS_PER_GROUP = 4

class Identifier(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField()
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', related_named='identifiers')

    def clean(self):
        identifiers = self.group.identifiers.values_list('value', flat=True)

        # If a new identifier is being created, but the current group already has identifiers == MAX_IDENTIFIERS_PER_GROUP
        if not self.pk and len(identifiers) == Group.MAX_IDENTIFIERS_PER_GROUP:
            raise ValidationError(f'Cannot have more than {Group.MAX_IDENTIFIERS_PER_GROUP} identifiers for group {self.group.pk}')

        # If there is another group with the same values in identifiers as the current identifier's group
        conflicting_identifier = Identifier.objects
            .filter(value__in=set(identifiers + [self.value, ]))
            .exclude(group=self.group)
            .values('group')
            .annotate(value_count=Count('value'))
            .filter(value_count__gte=Group.MAX_IDENTIFIERS_PER_GROUP).first()

        if conflicting_identifier:
            raise ValidationError(f'Current identifier combination is already present in group {conflicting_identifier.group.pk}')
```

Note that the `clean` does not get run automatically in `save` so this needs to be manually used. (Haven't tested this but the gist should be clear ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Could do it via [validate_unique](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) method:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    ...

    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        qs = Identifier.objects.filter(group_id=self.id)
        # restrict a Group to only have at most 4 Identifiers
        if qs.count() >= 4:
            raise ValidationError("group already has 4 Identifiers")
        # Ensure that any combination of up to 4 Identifiers is unique across all Groups
        values = []
        for group in Group.objects.all():
            values.append([i.value for i in group.identifiers])
        current_values = [i.value for i in self.identifiers]
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483730/python-check-if-list-of-lists-of-lists-contains-a-specific-list
        if current_values in values:
            raise ValidationError("group with these identifiers already exists")
```

This is pseudo code so might not work - but you get the idea :)

Comment: Sounds good, but it won't get called at the correct moment. It will get called upon group save, were it should be on identifier save instead (as it holds the reference, it will be the one getting saved). Maybe calling self.group.validate_unique() from the identifier clean method could do it, but I'm not sure the list will be up to date at this moment (as the identifier is not saved yet)